# listen for events on .load() content.

Tags: jquery

I have a nav menu that loads conditionally based on session state.

The one of menu looks like this ..

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu" >
            <li id="index"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</li>
            <li><a href="addhook.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register Site</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Favorites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Log out</a></li>
        <ul>
```

to load it I `$("#navbar").load("unauthNav.html");` to act on items in the menu I can use a call back but I am not sure how to listen for taps after the menu is loaded as it does not seem to enter the DOM.

If it were loaded with the DOM I would use a click handler within `$( document ).ready()` I have tried `.on` but this does not work either. e.g

```
var navMain = $(".menu");
  navMain.on("click", "li", null, function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  navMain.collapse('hide');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on click event handler on document rather than navmain as below

```
  document.on("click", ".menu li", null, function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  navMain.collapse('hide');
})
```